# how to apply for-loop in between string data to create an order in shopify through api

Tags: c#, string, api, loops, shopify

```
string data = @"  
               {
                ""order"": {  
                 ""line_items"": [
                    {
                    ""variant_id"":" + varientid_arr[0] +@",
                    ""quantity"":" + quantity_arr[0] + @"
                    }
                   ],
                    ""customer"": {
                                  ""id"": 2750996643918
                                  },
                    ""financial_status"": ""pending""
                    }
                 }
                 ";
```

in this code i want to iterate line items(varientid_arr[0], quantity_arr[0] ) for creating order with multiple products in shopify.  i want to apply for loop in line items only within string.

Comment: I cannot fully understand what is the end result you are trying to accomplish. Is it a single string or multiple strings?
Can you provide an example as what you expect the final result to be (after applying the for)?

Comment: Other than the intent not being clear; StackOverflow expects you to post your attempts at solving this issue. As it currently stands, your question shows no such attempts and is off-topic. Either ask a concrete question (that is not trivially googleable) or show a concrete problem (with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use Linq's Select method:

```
string data = @"  
              {
                ""order"": {  
                  ""line_items"": [" +

                    string.Join(",\n", varientid_arr.Select((varientid, index) =>
                    @"{
                      ""variant_id"":" + varientid +@",
                      ""quantity"":" + quantity_arr[index] + @"
                     }") +

                  @"],
                  ""customer"": {
                    ""id"": 2750996643918
                  },
                  ""financial_status"": ""pending""
                }
              }";
```

The key is that you're using select to build a new string out of each element in the varientid_arr list. But since you're using 2 lists, you need access to the index at each element of varientid so that you can get the correct quantity item. Select has an overload for this where the lambda accepts the item at each iteration and the index.

DISCLAIMER: I would not recommend this. Any time you want to template out strings doing complicated things like this, use more readable ways and more robust methods. Don't just jam it all into a single statement like this.

You might consider breaking each part of the string into a function, then building the string by calling each function and putting them together.

Here's an incomplete example.

```
string orderJson = GetOrderJson(varrientid_arr, quantity_arr);
string customerJson = GetCustomerJson();
string financialStatusJson = GetFinancialStatus();

string data = $"{{ ""order"": {orderJson}, ""customer"": {customerJson}, ""financial_status"": {financialStatusJson} }}";
```

Comment: thanks.. my order created successfully.

Comment: Great! would you mark this as accepted then?